Controller endless loop after migration to Spring 6
I am on the way to do the migration from Spring 5 to 6 and now got a strange problem: The method of my webmvc controller is called endless.
My code is just the following:
SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer 
  extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}

WebMvcApplicationInitializer.java

public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends
  AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { SecurityConfig.class, WebMvcConfig.class 
  };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

}

WebMvcConfig.java

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
 "com.feedbager"
})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry {
    registry
        .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
 
}

SecurityConfig.java

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.feedbager")
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) 
  throws Exception {
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = 
            http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
}

@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return web -> web.ignoring()
            .requestMatchers("/resources/**");
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
      .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry ->
              authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry
                .requestMatchers("/shop/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_SHOP")
                .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .requestMatchers("/manufacturer/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_MANUFACTURER")
                .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/index").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/accessDenied").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/verify").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/shops").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/manufacturers").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/articles").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(form -> form
                    .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler).loginProcessingUrl("/process-login").loginPage("/index").failureUrl("/index?error")
                    .permitAll()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement(httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer -> httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}

@Autowired
private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Autowired
private LoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler;

I was running the same configuration with Spring 5 before.
Is there something new with Spring 6 regarding controllers and the return?
I am expecting that the method is only called once

This is too little information. What have you debugged so far, where do the calls come from, is there a customized Spring Security in place, are other filters involved, ...

Well I have no others filters, but a Spring Security in use, where I have to say that the same configuration running correct with Spring 5. Added my security config in the post

Spring Boot 3, respectively Spring Security 6 come literally with MAJOR upgrades. So just upgrading without background knowledge and adapting to all the new things would probably with a certainity of 100% not work. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/Spring-Security-6.0-Migration-Guide

Well I got the configuration from my researches from the web, so I thought I was good prepared with everything

Additional 2 cents: I know that implementing a working AuthenticationManager for Spring Security 6 is quite a pain in the ass, and as long as you don't have a very good reason to do this as well as the knowledge of how to do it, you should avoid providing your own AuthenticationManager. In most cases it is sufficient to have a custom ProviderManager in place to bundle all your active AuthenticationProviders. - Anyhow, in your example I don't see any reason for even building a ProviderManager at all, since you just add the only AuthenticationProvider Spring can find.

Which method is being called repeatedly? Perhaps sharing logs in your question will help me understand what is going on

Well I dont know why but the problem with the method which is called endless, is solved. But one other thing: I have my index page which also include the login form, with action="index". I have configured that as you see in my code. I have my own AuthenticationProvider and an own LoginSuccessHandler. But when submitting the login form, the AuthenticationProvider is not called and the page index is loaded again. Any idea? The same configuration had worked with Spring 5 and Security 5

I have now edit my first post and give all my configuration spring code. Therewith I really  have the strange behaviour that the index method of my controller is called again, and again and again
